# How to import a sequence of Excel Files in matlab as a column vectors or as a cell array?

Tags: matlab

I want to import a sequence of excel files with a large amount of data in them. The problem that I have is I want to process the data in each file at a time and store the output from this into a variable, but each time I try to process a different file the variable gets overwritten in the variable workspace. Is there anyway I could store these files and process each file at a time?

```
numFiles = 1; 
range = 'A2:Q21'; 
sheet = 1; 
myData = cell(1,numFiles); % Importing data from Excel 
for fileNum = 1:numFiles 
  fileName = sprintf('myfile%02d.xlsx',fileNum); 
  myData{fileNum} = importfile3(fileName,sheet,range); 
end 
data = cell2mat(myData);
```

The actual data import is performed by `importfile3` which is, for the most part, a wrapper for the `xlsread` function that returns a matrix corresponding to the specified range of excel data.

```
function data = importfile3(workbookFile, sheetName, range)
% If no sheet is specified, read first sheet
if nargin == 1 || isempty(sheetName)
    sheetName = 1;
end

% If no range is specified, read all data
if nargin <= 2 || isempty(range)
    range = '';
end

%% Import the data 
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread(workbookFile, sheetName, range);

%% Replace non-numeric cells with 0.0
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) || isnan(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {0.0}; % Replace non-numeric cells

%% Create output variable 
data = cell2mat(raw);
```

Comment: Can you post a few code snippets?

Comment: numFiles = 1;
range = 'A2:Q21';
sheet = 1;
myData = cell(1,numFiles);

% Importing data from Excel
for fileNum = 1:numFiles
    fileName = sprintf('myfile%02d.xlsx',fileNum);
    myData{fileNum} = importfile3(fileName,sheet,range);

end

data = cell2mat(myData);

Comment: This is the code I am using to import excel files.And then there is a code for proceesing on the data in the file.

Comment: It looks like the meat of your code is in the `importfile3` function. Can you include this code?  Have you considered using [xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) instead? When you say that your data is getting overwritten, do you mean that on each iteration of your for loop, `myData` is not being updated the way that you intended?

Comment: myData is getting updated.But when I convert the cell to matrix using cell2mat I am not able to access the different cells in the cell array.

Comment: importfile 3 code:function data = importfile3(workbookFile, sheetName, range)

% If no sheet is specified, read first sheet
if nargin == 1 || isempty(sheetName)
    sheetName = 1;
end

% If no range is specified, read all data
if nargin <= 2 || isempty(range)
    range = '';
end

%% Import the data
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread(workbookFile, sheetName, range);

%% Replace non-numeric cells with 0.0
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) || isnan(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {0.0}; % Replace non-numeric cells

%% Create output variable
data = cell2mat(raw);

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are running in to is a result of `cell2mat` concatenating all of the data in your cells in to one large 2-dimensional matrix.  If you were to import two excel files with 20 rows and 17 columns, each, this would result in a 2-dimensional matrix of size *[20 x 34]*.  The [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) for `cell2mat` has a nice visual describing this.

I see that your `importfile3` function returns a matrix, and based on your use of `cell2mat` in your final line of code, it looks like you would like to have your final result be in the form of a matrix.  So I think the easiest way to go about this is to just bypass the intermediate `myData` cell array.

In the example code below, the resulting `data` is a 3-dimensional matrix.  The 1st dimension indicates row number, 2nd dimension is column number, and 3rd dimension is file number.  Cell arrays are very useful for "jagged" data, but based on the code you provided, each excel data set that you import will have the same number of rows and columns.

```
numFiles = 2; 
range = 'A2:Q21'; 
sheet = 1; 

% Number of rows and cols known before data import
numRows = 20;
numCols = 17;

data = zeros(numRows,numCols,numFiles);
for fileNum = 1:numFiles 
   fileName = sprintf('myfile%02d.xlsx',fileNum); 
   data(:,:,fileNum) = importfile3(fileName,sheet,range);
end
```

Accessing this data is now very straight-forward.

`data(:,:,1)` returns the data imported from your first excel file.
`data(:,:,2)` returns the data imported from your second excel file.
etc.

Comment: Can I import data from multiple excel sheets from the same file?And also in the above example I have a large Excel file .What if I dont know the ncols and nrows beforehand?

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in main6 (line 22)
   data(:,:,fileNum) = importfile3(fileName,sheet,range);

Comment: Based on the usage of `importfile3` that you provided in your example code, you are specifying the range (i.e. 'A2:Q21' in this case) therefore you ***will*** know the exact number of rows and columns that `importfile3` should be expected to return.  If the file has more rows/cols than the specified range, they won't be returned.  If it has fewer, the data will be zero-padded.  I'm guessing that the error that you are receiving is because there is a mismatch between the `range` that you specify and the values for `numRows` and `numCols`. For example, `range = 'A2:Q21'` has 20 rows and 17 cols.